# Does Johnny Bravo Ever get a girlfriend?

Tags: johnny-bravo

I remember watching Johnny Bravo when I was a kid and through out the series he is portrayed as a macho narcissistic guy trying to hit on women all the time and fail miserably. I never did get a chance to get through the series completely.

[image]

Does he find true love/get a girl friend at any part in the series?

Comment: Many times.....but in the end he leaves her because of her defects and other reason. There is one episode where his gf is wolf.

Comment: Can you be specific as to the episode name or #?

Comment: [Topic of the Week Winner](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/479/topic-of-the-week)

Comment: @Dredd her name was [Fluffy](http://johnnybravo.wikia.com/wiki/Fluffy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading through the [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Johnny_Bravo_episodes) of episodes confirms that no, he never did get a girlfriend.