# Why does Johnny Bravo have trouble finding a girl to date?

Tags: character, johnny-bravo

With such a chiseled body, Johnny Bravo still has trouble finding a girl to date. Why is that?

My question is different from [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/does-johnny-bravo-ever-get-a-girlfriend).

Comment: For the plot of course. Maybe the creator hates the "Chad" stereotype and seeks to never reveal its success by portraying that all women simply "know better", and then everyone laughed and laughed...

Comment: It's hard out there.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Because he is self-centered and egotistical.

The cartoon tries to show that good looks are not enough to get a girlfriend - you also need to show some sort of character and treat the (potential) girlfriend as something more than a future worshiper of yourself.

The whole cartoon can be summarized with a single quote:

[image]

Comment: There's actually a [JB episode on exactly this subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIPpJNGYAOY) (featuring the voice from Schoolhouse Rock, animated in the style of Schoolhouse Rock).

Comment: ...with a very amusing twist...

Comment: This is just a variation on the accepted answer. Johnny is unable to find a love interest,
because he is in love with himself.

Comment: Well... I know *plenty* of women who would fall exactly for such a guy... (they will probably get disillusioned later, probably months or years later, but that's a different story)

Comment: @vsz In a "realistic" show, Johnny Bravo would probably be dating someone you described. The thing is, Johnny Bravo is very much the "bad guy", the personification of what a lovable man should not be. So in an ideal world, we don't *want* him to ever find a girlfriend.